# React native typescript error thrown when using Animated value

Tags: node.js, express

I'm facing the following `TypeError` when trying to add an `Animated.value` to an inline-style property.

```
Type '{ width: number; height: Animated.Value; paddingBottom: number; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

I have tried to set the style property to:

```
Animated.AnimatedProps<StyleProp<ViewStyle>>
```

but looks like it's not the proper type for this...

That's the code:

```js
{...}

const MidScreenModal = ({onClose}: MidScreenModalProps) => {
  {...}

  const positionAnim = useRef(
    new Animated.Value(Dimensions.get('window').height / 2),
  ).current;

  {...} 

  return (
    <Modal transparent>
      <StyledModalFakeBg>
        <StyledModal
          style={{
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
            height: positionAnim, <--- ERROR HERE
            paddingBottom: bottom,
          }}>
          <MarginBottomView style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Bar />
          </MarginBottomView>
        </StyledModal>
      </StyledModalFakeBg>
    </Modal>
  );
};

{...}

interface StyledModalProps {
  style?: Animated.AnimatedProps<StyleProp<ViewStyle>>;
}

const StyledModal = styled.View<StyledModalProps>`
  {...}
`;

export default MidScreenModal;
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to make the View animated...Fixed doing:

```
const StyledModal = styled(Animated.View)<StyledModalProps>`
  background-color: ${DARK_LIGHT};
  padding: ${PADDING_LG}px;
`;
```